# Detecting swipe gestures in WebView disallows clicks in it

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-webview, android-view

I have a `WebView` and I am implementing a `TouchListener` to it which can detect horizontal swipe.

```
webView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    when ( event.action ) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> x1 = event.x
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            x2 = event.x
            val distance = Math.abs( x2 - x1 )
            if ( distance >= thresholdDistance ) {
                if ( webView.canGoBack() ) {
                    webView.goBack()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    true
}
```

This can detect swipes on the `WebView`, but the problem is, when the user clicks on a link in the `WebView`, the `WebView` does not respond. Also, the scrolling of the `WebView` doesn't work.

> What is the best way to handle clicks as well as to detect swipes on a `WebView`?

Comment: Don't return as `true` always, only return true where you suppose to intercept touch event otherwise return as `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are consuming the touch event even apart from swipe, returning `true` means that you are consuming the entire event, by what it won't get propagate to the parent.

**@return True only for the event you suppose to consume, false otherwise**

You can modify your code like below

```
webView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    when ( event.action ) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> x1 = event.x
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            x2 = event.x
            val distance = Math.abs( x2 - x1 )
            if ( distance >= thresholdDistance ) {
                if ( webView.canGoBack() ) {
                    webView.goBack()
                }
                true
            }
        }
    }
    false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Krishna Sharma. You made my day!